# Select AVG of rows with the same `name`

Tags: mysql, select, average

This is my table:

```
id | name | value
1  | name1 | 4
2  | name1 | 3
3  | name2 | 5
4  | name2 | 1
```

How to get complete table and AVG() of rows with the same value in `name` in one query?

Sorry for my bad english and thanks for help :)

Comment: It would be easier if you show the answer you expect for the query in your example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use simple `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT name,
       avg(value)
FROM t3
GROUP BY name;
```